# AuthKEY REST - Role service from REST endpoint

Tags: django, rest, geoserver

I'm trying to setup Geonode and Geoserver advance security. I'm currently doing setup for the Geoserver.

I'm stuck at this step [Setup of the GeoNode REST Role Service](http://docs.geonode.org/en/master/tutorials/admin/geoserver_geonode_security/#setup-of-the-geonode-rest-role-service). 
I cannot add new role service as i did not have `AuthKEY REST - Role service from REST endpoint` in the role service option.

[AuthKEY REST - Role service from REST endpoint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fK9I6.png).

currently using

1. **Django (1.6.11)**
2. **Geoserver 2.4.7**
3. **GeoNode (2.4.dev20170302183855, /vagrant/geonode)**
4. **django-oauth-toolkit (0.7.2)**

Answer (score 0):

download the jar gs-authkey (https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.geoserver.community/gs-authkey/2.11.1), copy to geoserver/WEB-INF/lib/

works for me!

Comment: that plugin only add to authentication filter as **authkey**. still not appear in the role service.

Answer (score 0):

In order to user geoserver authkey plugin the geoserver version and the plugin have to be the same version.
It seems that there is no auth key plugin for that geoserver version(2.4.7). You have to upgrade your geoserver version for a minimum version 2.5.2 if you use [maven repository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.geoserver.community/gs-authkey) or 2.15.3 if you use [official geoserver repository](https://sourceforge.net/projects/geoserver/files/GeoServer/2.15.3/extensions/).

The procedure of installing the geoserver and geoserver authkey plugin in tomcat is as follows:

1. Download the plugin from http://geoserver.org/download/, choose your GeoServer version(geoserver-${GEOSERVER_VERSION}-war.zip) and download the auth key plugin in the extension section(geoserver-${GEOSERVER_VERSION}-authkey-plugin.zip).
   Note: Make sure that your geoserver version is the same as geoserver authkey plugin.
2. Extract geoserver archive and put geoserver.war file to $TOMCAT_HOME/webapps.
3. Extract geoserver auth key plugin to $TOMCAT_HOME/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib(copy all jar files).
4. Restart Tomcat.
5. Make sure your Catalog Mode is set as "HIDE".

This is the offical documentation for [geoserver REST roles service](https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/security/usergrouprole/roleservices.html).